# how to run a .cs file other than Program.cs file in the same c# Console Application?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I created a console application with which it created program.cs file but I created different class within the same project with main method in it. How can run my new class? Every time I run my app, it keeps executing Program.cs in console application. Can you please direct me with right path?

Answer (score 5):

Since, you say, every time `Program.cs` is running,

Delete `Main()` from it, and put it in the `.cs` file which you want.

But you can create instances of a class anywhere, provided you have a refernce to it.

`Main()` looks like this:

```
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                 // Do something here.
            }
```

Whatever `.cs` contains, `Main()` method will get executed first.

Note: You shouldn't have two `Main()` methods. It will throw an error

Answer (score 0):

inside `program.cs` construct your new class and call a method on it.